# Glassfish 4 do not load js files

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, jboss, glassfish

I have moved recently 
        from 
           glassfish 3.1, jsf 2.0, primefaces 3.5, java 6 
        to
           glassfish 4, jsf 2.2, primefaces 5, java 8

Javascript files(Primefaces javascript files usually) not being loaded often, but sometimes it being loaded and everything works fine. It gives the following exception

```
[2014-09-03T08:49:30.421+0400] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=23 _ThreadName=Thread-3] [timeMillis: 1409719770421] [levelValue: 800] [[
  entered to constructor]]

[2014-09-03T08:49:30.437+0400] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=23 _ThreadName=Thread-3] [timeMillis: 1409719770437] [levelValue: 800] [[
  done constructor]]

[2014-09-03T08:49:30.578+0400] [glassfish 4.0] [WARNING] [] [javax.enterprise.web.core] [tid: _ThreadID=21 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1409719770578] [levelValue: 900] [[
  Error invoking requestInitialized method on ServletRequestListener org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldListener
java.lang.IllegalStateException: isHexDigit
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.util.URLDecoder.decode(URLDecoder.java:470)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.util.Parameters.processParameters(Parameters.java:652)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.util.Parameters.processParameters(Parameters.java:687)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.util.Parameters.handleQueryParameters(Parameters.java:335)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.Request.parseRequestParameters(Request.java:1995)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.Request.getParameter(Request.java:1052)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getParameter(Request.java:1547)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getParameter(RequestFacade.java:448)
    at org.jboss.weld.servlet.ConversationContextActivator.getConversationId(ConversationContextActivator.java:115)
    at org.jboss.weld.servlet.ConversationContextActivator.activateConversationContext(ConversationContextActivator.java:82)
    at org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldListener.requestInitialized(WeldListener.java:201)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.fireRequestInitializedEvent(StandardContext.java:5225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.preInvoke(StandardHostValve.java:647)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
]]

[2014-09-03T08:49:30.593+0400] [glassfish 4.0] [WARNING] [] [javax.enterprise.web.core] [tid: _ThreadID=21 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1409719770593] [levelValue: 900] [[
  Error invoking requestDestroyed method on ServletRequestListener org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldListener
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jboss.weld.context.AbstractBoundContext.deactivate(AbstractBoundContext.java:71)
    at org.jboss.weld.context.http.HttpRequestContextImpl.deactivate(HttpRequestContextImpl.java:70)
    at org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldListener.requestDestroyed(WeldListener.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.fireRequestDestroyedEvent(StandardContext.java:5261)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.postInvoke(StandardHostValve.java:255)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:359)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
]]

[2014-09-03T08:49:30.593+0400] [glassfish 4.0] [WARNING] [] [javax.enterprise.web.core] [tid: _ThreadID=21 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1409719770593] [levelValue: 900] [[
  Error invoking requestInitialized method on ServletRequestListener org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldListener
java.lang.IllegalStateException: isHexDigit
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.util.URLDecoder.decode(URLDecoder.java:470)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.util.Parameters.processParameters(Parameters.java:652)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.util.Parameters.processParameters(Parameters.java:687)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.util.Parameters.handleQueryParameters(Parameters.java:335)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.Request.parseRequestParameters(Request.java:1995)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.Request.getParameter(Request.java:1052)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getParameter(Request.java:1547)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getParameter(RequestFacade.java:448)
    at org.jboss.weld.servlet.ConversationContextActivator.getConversationId(ConversationContextActivator.java:115)
    at org.jboss.weld.servlet.ConversationContextActivator.activateConversationContext(ConversationContextActivator.java:82)
    at org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldListener.requestInitialized(WeldListener.java:201)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.fireRequestInitializedEvent(StandardContext.java:5225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.preInvoke(StandardHostValve.java:647)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
]]

[2014-09-03T08:49:30.593+0400] [glassfish 4.0] [WARNING] [] [javax.enterprise.web.core] [tid: _ThreadID=21 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1409719770593] [levelValue: 900] [[
  Error invoking requestDestroyed method on ServletRequestListener org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldListener
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jboss.weld.context.AbstractBoundContext.deactivate(AbstractBoundContext.java:71)
    at org.jboss.weld.context.http.HttpRequestContextImpl.deactivate(HttpRequestContextImpl.java:70)
    at org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldListener.requestDestroyed(WeldListener.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.fireRequestDestroyedEvent(StandardContext.java:5261)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.postInvoke(StandardHostValve.java:255)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:359)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
]]

[2014-09-03T08:49:31.203+0400] [glassfish 4.0] [WARNING] [] [javax.enterprise.web.core] [tid: _ThreadID=21 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1409719771203] [levelValue: 900] [[
  Error invoking requestInitialized method on ServletRequestListener org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldListener
java.lang.IllegalStateException: isHexDigit
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.util.URLDecoder.decode(URLDecoder.java:470)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.util.Parameters.processParameters(Parameters.java:652)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.util.Parameters.processParameters(Parameters.java:687)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.util.Parameters.handleQueryParameters(Parameters.java:335)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.Request.parseRequestParameters(Request.java:1995)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.Request.getParameter(Request.java:1052)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getParameter(Request.java:1547)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getParameter(RequestFacade.java:448)
    at org.jboss.weld.servlet.ConversationContextActivator.getConversationId(ConversationContextActivator.java:115)
    at org.jboss.weld.servlet.ConversationContextActivator.activateConversationContext(ConversationContextActivator.java:82)
    at org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldListener.requestInitialized(WeldListener.java:201)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.fireRequestInitializedEvent(StandardContext.java:5225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.preInvoke(StandardHostValve.java:647)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
]]

[2014-09-03T08:49:31.203+0400] [glassfish 4.0] [WARNING] [] [javax.enterprise.web.core] [tid: _ThreadID=21 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1409719771203] [levelValue: 900] [[
  Error invoking requestDestroyed method on ServletRequestListener org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldListener
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jboss.weld.context.AbstractBoundContext.deactivate(AbstractBoundContext.java:71)
    at org.jboss.weld.context.http.HttpRequestContextImpl.deactivate(HttpRequestContextImpl.java:70)
    at org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldListener.requestDestroyed(WeldListener.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.fireRequestDestroyedEvent(StandardContext.java:5261)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.postInvoke(StandardHostValve.java:255)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:359)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
]]
```

thanks

Comment: Related/dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24981151/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-urldecoder-incomplete-trailing-escape-pa To the point, GF4 is not intented for production. It's only intented for "reference". Use a different server. It's by the way surprising to see you tagging `[jboss]`.

Comment: Thank you and sorry about that :)

Comment: I would have suggested to use JBoss instead, but you basically already knew that.

Comment: Thanks. you mean WildFly, am I right?